# Rails 4+: single resource with several associations, controller organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, dry, code-organization

This is one of those "real world project" problems that I am struggling to find a good solution to.

I have a `task` model that is associated to several different resources and I need to allow CRUD ability from each of those associated resources.

For instance, a `project` has many `tasks` and I need to update the `tasks` in context of the `project`.

Also, each `project` has many `milestones`, and each `milestone` also can have many `tasks`.

It's a situation where a `task` may or may not be associated to a `milestone`.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :milestones
  has_many :tasks
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project # required
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project # required
  belongs_to :milestone # optional
end
```

I have namespaced my controllers for better organization and control.  That leads me with routes such as:

```
# routes.rb
resources :projects do
  namespace :projects do
    resources :milestones # app/controllers/projects/milestones_controller.rb
    resources :tasks # app/controllers/projects/tasks_controller.rb
  end
end

resources :milestones do
  namespace :milestones do
    resources :tasks # app/controllers/milestones/tasks_controller.rb
  end
end
```

I also am using a lot of AJAX to make the interface faster (with Turbolinks), so my actions follow the `<action>.js.erb` format where I use JavaScript to update the page instead of page refreshes.  Note that I'm using a dialog/popup interface for the `task` forms as well, hence why I can't just do entire page refreshes.

While this "works", it ends up with a situation where I have a lot of duplicate code.

```
# projects/tasks_controller.rb
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.new(task_params)

  if @task.save
    # create.js.erb
  else
    render js: "alert('error');" # example...
  end
end

# app/views/projects/tasks/create.js.erb
$("#tasks_for_<%= dom_id(@project) %>").append("<%=j render(partial: 'projects/tasks/task') %>");

# milestones/tasks_controller.rb
def new
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:milestone_id])
  @task = @milestone.tasks.new
end

def create
  @milestone = Milestone.find(params[:milestone_id])
  @task = @milestone.tasks.new(task_params)

  if @task.save
    # create.js.erb
  else
    render js: "alert('error');" # example...
  end
end

# app/views/milestones/tasks/create.js.erb
$("#tasks_for_<%= dom_id(@milestone) %>").append("<%=j render(partial: 'milestones/tasks/task') %>");
```

This is just some sample code, the code from the actual system shows even more duplication.  As you can tell, there's a lot of repeat code in each of the different resources that interact slightly different with the `tasks` resource.

Is there some standard format or Rails feature that assists with structuring resources that are manipulated by several other resources?

How could I decrease this duplication?  It is directly leading to a complex system where everytime I add or change a feature, I have to go and change it in 3+ different places.

Comment: This is exactly why you should be using presenters, services, managers, etc. (all plain old ruby objects).

Comment: @jvillian: I do use presenters and service objects and other PORO.  But I'm not sure how those would help with reducing the duplication in controllers and views as mentioned above?  The issue is really that 3+ places use 90% of the same code, and I'm not sure how to DRY up the code yet still allow for that 10% difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `ServiceBase` that looks something like this:

```
# services/service_base.rb
class ServiceBase

  attr_accessor :args,
                :controller

  class << self

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end

  private

    def params
      controller.params
    end

    def assign_args
      args.each do |k,v| 
        class_eval do 
          attr_accessor k
        end
        send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end

end
```

And then a `Tasks::NewService` that looks something like this:

```
# services/tasks/new_service.rb
class Tasks::NewService < ServiceBase

    def call
      assign_args
      @haser = haser_klass.find(haser_id)
      @haser.tasks.new
    end

  private

    def haser_klass
      haser_base.constantize
    end

    def haser_instance_name
      haser_base.downcase
    end

    def haser_base
      controller.class.name.split("::")[0].singularize
    end

    def haser_id
      params["#{haser_instance_name}_id".to_sym]
    end

end
```

Then, in your controllers, you should be able to do something like:

```
# milestones/tasks_controller.rb
Milestones::TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Tasks::NewService.call(controller: self)
  end

end

# projects/tasks_controller.rb
Projects::TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Tasks::NewService.call(controller: self)
  end

end
```

If you have a `Tasks::CreateService` that looks something like:

```
# services/tasks/create_service.rb
class Tasks::CreateService < ServiceBase

  delegate  :render,
            to: :controller

    def call 
      assign_args
      @haser = haser_klass.find(haser_id)
      @task = @haser.tasks.new(task_params)
      if @task.save
        # create.js.erb
      else
        render js: "alert('error');" # example...
      end      
    end

  private

    def task_params
      send("#{haser_instance_name}_params")
    end

    def milestone_params
      params.require(:milestone).permit(:foo)
    end

end
```

Then, in your controllers, you should be able to do something like:

```
# milestones/tasks_controller.rb
Milestones::TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Tasks::NewService.call(controller: self)
  end

  def create
    Tasks::CreateService.call(controller: self)
  end

end

# projects/tasks_controller.rb
Projects::TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Tasks::NewService.call(controller: self)
  end

  def new
    Tasks::CreateService.call(controller: self)
  end

end
```

If you get to a point where, after abstraction, your controllers have identical methods, then you could start to do other fancy stuff like have `Milestones::TasksController` and `Projects::TasksController` both inherit from a common controller other than `ApplicationController` that has all the shared methods. So, let's say you're not using `TasksController`. Then, maybe your controllers could look something like:

```
# tasks_controller.rb
TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Tasks::NewService.call(controller: self)
  end

  def create
    Tasks::CreateService.call(controller: self)
  end

end    

# milestones/tasks_controller.rb
Milestones::TasksController < TasksController; end

# projects/tasks_controller.rb
Projects::TasksController < TasksController; end
```

Now, you only need to make changes in one place: in your services. Naturally, you can always override controller methods if you don't want to use the services.

Comment: I did go the route of using a shared "base" controller and then the different associations inherit from it.  It allowed me to cleanup several lookup methods, but still allowed for flexibility in each.